# Can't create a vector_float 3 in xcode 7 Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

Trying to create a linearGravityField in Swift and can't create a vector_float3 variable to pass in the argument of the function

SKFieldNode.linearGravityFieldWithVector(direction: vector_float3)

Any idea how to create one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SKFieldNode.linearGravityFieldWithVector(vector_float3(1,1,1))
```

Comment: That was the only thing I didn't try. I feel stupid now.

Comment: You have understood my answer perfectly. Seriously, there is no need to "try". `vector_float3` is a struct like any other struct: you can look right at the declaration and see what the initializers are. You don't have to guess.

Comment: @matt: That's not true, at least not in the latest iOS SDK (9.3 at time of writting).  `vector_float3`'s declaration looks like this: `typedef __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(3))) float vector_float3;`  That's all you get.  It's a `float`, with some wonky `__attribute__`.  How to initialize it or access elements of it remains an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Worse, Apple's docs give only a not-so-helpful _“A floating point vector type used to perform physics calculations.”_ and the same typedef found in the `vector_types.h` header  ( https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKFieldNode_Ref/ ).  The only place I've been able to find any docs on how to use these things is the Clang Language Extensions docs, under Vectors and Extended Vectors ( http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#vectors-and-extended-vectors ).  Their recommended method of defining a literal is C's `(vector float){ 1, 1, 1 }` syntax.

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson That http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#vectors-and-extended-vectors is a good link.

Comment: Apple's docs fail at this one, but when you command+click on it in Xcode, you get shown that: `public typealias vector_float3 = float3`, and float3 is what you'd expect. A struct with x, y, and z variables.